# 403 error when trying to access Google Drive API in Android app

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to access the Google Drive API in my app using the guide at [REST API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android), however when I run the app I get a 403 forbidden error message that tells me that the Drive API is not enabled for my project.

I don't understand why this is or how to fix it.  The Drive API is definitely enabled in the Google Developer's Console and is set up as with OAuth 2.0 credentials, along with any other API's that I thought might be related.  The full error screen grab is shown in the link:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you used a different package name than the one in the example, then you might have forgotten to change it in the codes...like make sure you have the package name correctly set in the **build.module**, manifest...it happens when you just copy and paste stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Check [google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled) make sure drive SDK and drive API are enabled.

They both need to be enabled for some of the requests.

[image]

Comment: I can't find a Drive SDK, could it have been renamed to something else?

Comment: Doubt it I took that picture today

Comment: No results matching Drive SDK when I use the search box on the developers console.  Could it have something to do with the button at the top right of my developer console telling me to sign up for a free trial?  Maybe I'm locked out of certain features or something at the moment?